# How to prevent error recursive constructor invocation

Tags: java, recursion, constructor

I can't find the solution. I'm using Java 11 and IntelliJ IDEA.
Error is in line 10, only removing it gets rid of error, but I need this constructor.

The first time I encounter this error

```
public class Time2 {
    private int seconds;

    public Time2()
    {
        this(0);
    }

    public Time2(int hour)
    {
        this(hour*3600);
    }

    public Time2(int hour, int minute )
    {
        this(hour * 3600 + minute*60);
    }

    public Time2(int hour, int minute, int second)
    {

        if (hour < 0 || hour >= 24)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hour must be 0-23");

        if (minute < 0 || minute >= 60)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("minute must be 0-59");

        if (second < 0 || second >= 60)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("second must be 0-59");

        this.seconds = hour*3600 + minute*60 + second;
    }

    public Time2(Time2 time)
    {
        this(time.getHour(), time.getMinute(), time.getSecond());
    }

}
```

Comment: `this(hour*3600)` calls the same constructor recursively. Don't do it. Most probably, you wanted to call `this(hour*3600, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second constructor looks like this:

```
public Time2(int hour) {
        this(hour*3600);
}
```

Note that it invokes itself (that is called recursive invocation). And constructors can't invoke itself in this way. You probably wanted to set the `seconds` fields instead:

```
public Time2(int hour) {
        seconds = hour*3600;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive call between constructors:

```
public Time2() // A
{
    this(0);
}

public Time2(int hour) // B
{
    this(hour*3600);
}

public Time2(int hour, int minute ) // C
{
    this(hour * 3600 + minute*60);
}

public Time2(int hour, int minute, int second) // D
{

    if (hour < 0 || hour >= 24)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("hour must be 0-23");

    if (minute < 0 || minute >= 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("minute must be 0-59");

    if (second < 0 || second >= 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("second must be 0-59");

    this.seconds = hour*3600 + minute*60 + second;
}

public Time2(Time2 time) // E
{
    this(time.getHour(), time.getMinute(), time.getSecond());
}
```

- A -> B
- B -> B
- C -> B
- D -> -
- E -> D

So for constructors A, B, C, they all call B, and from there on an endless recursive call occurs.

You must correct the C and B constructors:

```
public Time2(int hour, int minute ) // C
{
    this(hour, minute, 0);
}

public Time2(int hour) // B
{
     this(hour,0);
}
```

This way the endless recursiveness is avoided.

- A -> B
- B -> C
- C -> D
- D -> -
- E -> D

Also only in the last (D) constructor the conversion to seconds occur.

PS: You should use Java already existing API to convert to seconds (ex:  `Duration.ofHours(1).getSeconds()`).